# Java: How to put values into a object from a list of randomly generated numbers

Tags: java, random, netbeans, min

Ok so I am new to Java and this is what I need to do.
Write a Java program that will allow a user to specify how many random numbers he/she would like to be generated between 1 and 100. Then produce the random and list them in your output. You should also compute the highest, lowest, sum and average. The part I need help on is getting the lowest and highest. I can't use arrays since we haven't really touched upon them yet.
what I need help doing throwing something in int lowest from my randomInt.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     Random rnd = new Random();
     int r;
     int sum = 0;
     int lowest=0;
     int highest=0;

     System.out.println("Please enter enter how many numbers "
             + "you would like to generate.");

     int userInput = sc.nextInt();

     for(r=1;r<=userInput;r++) 
    {  // was unsure how to remove the comma from the last number
        int randomInt = (int)(rnd.nextFloat()*100)+1;            
        System.out.print(randomInt + ",");

        sum += randomInt;

        if(randomInt < lowest)
        {
            lowest = randomInt;
        }            
    }    
     System.out.println(" The total sum of these random numbers are " 
             +sum);
     int average = sum / userInput;
     System.out.println("The average of all those numbers is "
             + average);
     System.out.println(lowest);
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. You've just posted requirements, code and nothing more.

Comment: sorry i edited it. what I need help doing is throwing something into int lowest from my randomInt. I don't what to do that.

Comment: You already have an assignment statement that does that.  `if(randomInt < lowest) {  lowest = randomInt; }`   What is your actual problem?

Comment: it always seems spits out 0 even though it should be different every time based on the numbers generated.

Comment: (Actually I can see what the problem is.  But you will learn more if you think this through for yourself.)  Question for you: under **exactly** what conditions will that assignment occur?

Comment: Thank you Stephen C I figured out. The condition was if(r == 1 || randomInt < lowest)

Comment: Actually ... no.  You missed the point.  The point is that zero is always going to be less or equal to `randomint`.  Look at how you declared and initialized `lowest`.

Comment: The thing is the moment I changed it to if(r == 1 || randomInt < lowest) it worked i always get the lowest value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lowest` was assigned to 0 and the range for your random generation of numbers is 1 to 100. In your code the only time the value of `lowest` changes is when the condition `randomInt < lowest` is satisfied, of course your program will always output 0 as the lowest.

Try changing the value of `lowest` to 100.

Comment: This also fixed it for me. but could you tell why if(r == 1 || randomInt < lowest) also fixed it.

Comment: Because at the first iteration of the loop, your `r` is equal to 1 and this satisfies the condition `r == 1`. As as result your `lowest` becomes the `randomInt` at the first iteration this causes your loop to function in finding the lowest value.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.